# So... why "wouldn't had"?

Tags: grammar

> Only once did he speak crossly to the monkey, and that was when he put him into the cage preparatory to commencing his morning's work.  Then he said:
>
> "You wouldn’t had to go into this place many times more if you hadn't been so wicked, for by to-morrow night we'd been away from this circus an' on the way to home an' Uncle Dan'l".

Is it archaic or it was perhaps, an erroneous yet preferred informal speech?, like when they say "You could of/coulda told me"... when it actually is "you could have told me".

"Toby Tyler" is a novel by James Otis published in 1877.

Comment: It's a proofreading error. It should be *You wouldn't **have** had to...*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a trivial proofreading error (*You wouldn't had to...* should be *You wouldn't **have** had to...*)

Comment: It’s also from 1877, and quite possible that a not very well educated man at that time would have spoken like that, and the sentence is as intended by the author. But “You wouldn’t have had to” is absolutely correct.

Comment: The author is obviously representing Toby's speech as 'uneducated'.

Comment: Note a similar construction later in the sentence, "... for by to-morrow night we'd been away from this circus," where it should be "we'd **have** been." It's dialect dialogue, just like all the "an'"s and "Dan'l."

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's from 1877. Why are you sure it's a proofreading error?

Comment: @gotube: Language changes, sure. But there was never either a time nor a regional dialect where it was acceptable to omit ***have*** (or at least ***'ve***) in the cited context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers We cannot know that one never existed. Even if you're right about that, the author could have invented grammar mistakes that he thought would pass for low class among his readers. That's not a proofreading mistake.

Comment: @gotube: In retrospect, I see it's not a proofreading error. But if I had to bet, I'd say your suggestion (the author erroneously invented grammar mistakes that he thought would pass for low class among his readers) is more likely than that he was faithfully replicating actual dialectal usage. It's just not the *kind* of grammar mistake I've ever seen before. It might be interesting to see if anyone at SO.linguistics could identify certain broad classes of "syntax error" that ***rarely*** occur among native Anglophones - as opposed to the ones children ***often*** come out with.

Answer (score 1):

The author purposefully put incorrect grammar into this character's mouth to indicate his lack of education and low class. I'm confident it's not a proofreading error because later in the same passage the character makes the same mistake of dropping "have" after "would" in an unreal conditional:

> ... by to-morrow night **we'd been** away from this circus...

This mistake is very similar to "could of/coulda", except the "have" is omitted altogether. I don't believe any modern day native speakers of any class, country or education level speak this way. This may have been a common error for lower-class people in 1877, or it could be a defect the author invented. Either way, if that were written today, it wouldn't even be recognizable as a speech error, and could only be a typo.